# Evaluation of Functions as arguments

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

I came across some Python code which I don't quite understand and would appreciate help with.

```
def take(count, iterable):
    counter = 0
    for item in iterable:
        if counter == count:
            return
        counter += 1
        yield item


def distinct(iterable):
    seen = set()
    for item in iterable:
        if item in seen:
            continue
        yield item
        seen.add(item)


def run_pipeline():
    items = [3, 6, 6, 2, 1, 1]
    for item in take(3, distinct(items)):
        print(item)

run_pipeline()
```

When I was debugging the code I noticed that when calling `take`, the call to `distinct` was not being evaluated first but rather called from `distinct`.  I could understand such behaviour had I passed `distinct` as just a name which would have referenced the object. I come from a C background where `distinct(items)` would be called before `take`.

Comment: `distinct(items)` creates a generator. When you iterate the generator, the code inside `def distinct(...)` is executed. That is the effect of having a `yield` statement in your function.

Comment: I don't understand what "the call to distinct was not being evaluated first but rather called from distinct" means.

Comment: I put print("take") and print("distinct") statements at the top of the relevant functions and take was printed first followed by distinct whereas I expected the opposite.